# How to Inserting french characters in mySQL DB table?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am having a major issue with inserting french characters in my mySQL DB. The french charaters doesn't display properly in the mysql table. For example "Éducation" is displayed as "ÃƒÂ‰ducation". I  have set the encoding to    utf8_unicode_ci. I have also tried the function htmlentities($string ,ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: the problem is the accents characters are not UTF-8 by default, they are iso-8859-1. how do you see the results from mysql ? (a terminal connect to mysql using mysql client ? a web page)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the php:

`header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

After connection:

`mysql_set_charset("utf8");`

Comment: It worked by giving  mysql_set_charset("utf8"); after connection

Answer (score 2):

Please check these:

- Database encoding
- Table encoding
- Field encoding
- Database connection encoding
- PHP runtime encoding
- .php and other files encoding
- Header encoding (HTTP header and/or HTML )

Answer (score 0):

first check the encoding of the table, then check the encoding of the insert.